# Short story about an endless space ship

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read it online few years ago. It is a short story about exploring a spacecraft/ship/station that seems to be infinite inside.

It is written like a log, and each entry starts with a measure, like Day 1 "1 km", Day 2 "10 km", Day 3 "100 km" (not sure about dimensions but they grew exponentially).

I found the story at that time while reading about megastructures. Although the construction in the story was huge, it didn't fit the criteria of megastructure because it was infinite.

Comment: This makes me think of "the Way" in Greg Bear's [Eon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eon_(novel)). But I don't recall if any of the chapters started with measurements like that. Also, this was a novel rather than a short story.

Comment: If you're interested in stories about seemingly infinite structures, you might enjoy reading House of Leaves by Mark Danielewski. This is not a short story though, but a full-blown book. It's also a typographical experiment, which makes it even more interesting. Take a look, maybe you'll enjoy it!

Comment: This is a good example of why story-id questions are a good feature of this site.  I read this, found the concept interesting, and found the answer and the link and just read this story.

Comment: @Lasooch: Typographical or topographical experiment?  There's a big difference!

Comment: @Tango actually, I guess one could say it's a bit of both. But mostly tYpography. Take a look: http://images.fanpop.com/images/image_uploads/Page-134-house-of-leaves-672677_971_1354.gif - an actual page from the book ;)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Year_in_the_Linear_City also comes to mind.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It is *[Report on an unidentified space station](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57618)* by J. G. Ballard. You can read a PDF version [here](http://www.paradiserow.com/usr/library/documents/main/j.g.-ballard-short-story.pdf) or an HTML version [here](http://geosci.uchicago.edu/%7Ekite/doc/roauss.htm).

Comment: That was a really neat story

Comment: Reminiscent of Borges' "Library of Babel".

Comment: This is why I love just to toddle around this page. Brilliant story

Comment: Yay for reading

Comment: D'aww, the link is broken...

Comment: I think it reminded me of Descending.

Comment: @moopet The HTML link still works.  Given that the entire story can be read in a couple minutes, HTML is not too bad.