# Short Story About an Empty Space Station with Increasingly Large Rooms

Tags: story-identification

Fragmented memories:

- A space station is discovered.
- May have been a by team of people who get split up?
- They board the space station.
- The space station is uninhabited.
- As they explore, the rooms start getting larger and larger.
- Eventually the last room is found which is actually the entire universe.
- I think it was written in the 70s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is JG Ballard's  *Report on an Unidentified Space Station*.

It was the subject of a previous question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65115/short-story-about-an-endless-space-ship), where you can find a link to read the story online.

Comment: This is it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Many years later Ballard went on to do a similar story set in an ordinary house. I can't remember the title but it was in Interzone in the 1990s.