# Astronaut lands on planet-sized artificial sphere, enters, takes ever-larger elevators into the interior

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have vague memories of this story - probably a short or novelette length published in a magazine like Analog in the 50s or 60s. A human space traveler lands on an artificial planet-sized sphere, finds his way inside, finds civilized beings, takes an elevator down a number of levels, gets out and takes a larger elevator further down, where he again finds an even larger elevator and heads down again.

The story, IIRC, had an odd single-word name like Kerplunk or Skiddoo.

Comment: [You can look up short story names on the ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/). Neither [Kerplunk](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=kerplunk&type=Fiction+Titles) nor [Skiddoo](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2271991) find any likely looking matches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Report on an Unidentified Space Station](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65115/short-story-about-an-endless-space-ship) - longer name, no aliens, but the rest is a straight match.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Ker-Plop](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41243), a novella by [Ted Reynolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Reynolds_(writer)), first published in [*Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine*, January 1979](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?59167), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v03n01_1979-01/page/n129/mode/1up).

> Gradually Cotter Oren’s mind fell out of nothingness into a
> semblance of existence. To exist was to fall, to drop deeper and
> deeper towards the center. To transfer to larger and larger
> elevators, descending deeper and deeper into a world, a universe,
> Galgaronok.